# Crosstab data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data in the PowerBI which I need to crosstab in order to generate the base data for a specific visual.

Example data:

```
tblExample = DATATABLE("Customer ID", INTEGER, "Gender", STRING, "Age Range", STRING, "Order Date", DATETIME, "WS Next Day", STRING, "Order Next Day", STRING, "WS Next Week", STRING, "Order Next Week", STRING, "WS Next Month", STRING, "Order Next Month", STRING,
    {
        {1, "Female", "30 - 39", "2017-02-09", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No" },
        {2, "Female", "30 - 39", "2017-02-11", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No" },
        {3, "Female", "50 - 59", "2017-02-12", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No" },
        {4, "Male", "20 - 29", "2017-02-12", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No" },
        {5, "Male", "40 - 49", "2017-02-19", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No" }
    }
)
```

This data shows customers who have placed an order and then a set of six yes / no flags showing whether or not the customer has visited the web site again the following day / week / month, and whether this visit resulted in another order.

What I need to do is turn this information into a table with one row for each category of "Next Day", "Next Week" and "Next Month", and for each row a value showing the count of customers who (a) visited and (b) purchased.

I thought this would be pretty straight forward to do in DAX - and to be honest I'm not sure that it isn't and I haven't just missed something really obvious - but at the moment I can't see a tidy way to achieve this.

I have created measures for each of the six values I need as follows:

```
NextDay_Visits = COUNTROWS(FILTER(tblExample, [WS Next Day] = "Yes"))
NextDay_Orders = COUNTROWS(FILTER(tblExample, [Order Next Day] = "Yes"))
```

And so on, and when I look at these measures in a card they give me the correct values, but to jam these into a table which is the correct shape I do the following (which is almost certainly the wrong way to do this in PowerBI !):

1  Create a new table

```
tblJunk1 = DATATABLE("Row ID", INTEGER, "Category", STRING, { {1, "Next Day"} })
```

2  Add the appropriate measures to the new table as new columns

```
tblJunk2 = ADDCOLUMNS(tblJunk1, "Visits", [NextDay_Visits], "Purchases", [NextDay_Purchases])
```

3  Do the same two steps again using tblJunk3 / tblJunk4 for the "Next Week" figures

4  Do the same two steps again using tblJunk5 / tblJunk6 for the "Next Month" figures.

5 Create a final table to use as the basis for my column chart by union-ing tblJunk2 / tblJunk4 / tblJunk6

```
tblChartBase = UNION(tblJunk2, tblJunk4, tblJunk6)
```

Then it's good news / bad news, because although this seems to me to be a horrible hack solution, I do get the table I need with the correct figures and the correct shape, and I can base a column chart on it which gives me the analysis I am looking for. (Good News!)

However, once I add slicers to the page based on "Gender" and "Age Group", the measures in this new table do not respond to them and the figures do not change meaning that this is not the way to achieve what I want.  (Bad News)

I am not sure whether I am kind of hedging around the correct methodology but need to tweak my DAX for the measures so they do respond to the slicers on the page, or whether this is totally the wrong approach from the ground up?

Any suggestions / pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

I would address this requirement in the Query Editor.  It has **Unpivot** functionality that should meet your needs, e.g.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

The Query Editor has added a few more options since that article was written, like **Unpivot Other Columns, Unpivot Only Selected Columns**.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this.  I did think I could unpivot in the Query Editor but the table tblExample built as above does not show up in the editor so this isn't an option.